# Django: Combining two for loops

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to combine the two for loops into one?
I was looking for a solution like this. But it didn't work that way:

```
ticket_stats_by_event = {
    x['pk']: {'sold_tickets': x['sold_tickets'], 'available_tickets: y['avaiable_tickets']}
    for x, y in sold_tickets_by_event, available_tickets_by_event
}
```

The result will be:

```
<EventQuerySet [{'pk': 6, 'organizer': 1, 'available_tickets': 20, 'sold_tickets': 2}, {'pk': 1, 'organizer': 1, 'available_tickets': 1765746, 'sold_tickets': 2116}, {'pk': 5, 'organizer': 1, 'available_tickets': 10, 'sold_tickets': 1}, {'pk': 4, 'organizer': 1, 'available_tickets': 60, 'sold_tickets': 4}]>
```

Here the full function:

```
def ticket_stats_by_event(self, organizer):
    sold_tickets_by_event = [
        x for x in self.sold_tickets if x['organizer'] == organizer.pk
    ]

    # <EventQuerySet [{'pk': 6, 'organizer': 1, 'sold_tickets': 1}, {'pk': 1, 'organizer': 1, 'sold_tickets': 529}, {'pk': 5, 'organizer': 1, 'sold_tickets': 1}, {'pk': 4, 'organizer': 1, 'sold_tickets': 2}]>


    available_tickets_by_event = [
        x for x in self.available_tickets if x['organizer'] == organizer.pk
    ]

    # <EventQuerySet [{'pk': 1, 'organizer': 1, 'available_tickets': 1721}, {'pk': 4, 'organizer': 1, 'available_tickets': 30}, {'pk': 5, 'organizer': 1, 'available_tickets': 10}, {'pk': 6, 'organizer': 1, 'available_tickets': 20}]>


    ticket_stats_by_event = {
        x['pk']: {'sold_tickets': x['sold_tickets']}
        for x in sold_tickets_by_event
    }

    for item in available_tickets_by_event:
        pk = item.pop('pk')
        ticket_stats_by_event[pk].update(item)

    return ticket_stats_by_event
```

Comment: Please show your models and describe **what** you are trying to accomplish instead of demonstrating **how** you're doing something.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your function like this using only a loop instead of four:

```
def ticket_stats_by_event(self, organizer):

    ticket_stats_by_event = {}

    for st, at in zip(self.sold_tickets, self.available_tickets):

        # if organizer is not same in any then skip
        if organizer.pk != st['organizer'] or organizer.pk != at['organizer']:
            continue

        st_pk = st['pk']
        st_value = {'sold_tickets': st['sold_tickets'], 'organizer': st['organizer']}
        at_pk = at['pk']
        at_value = {'available_tickets': at['available_tickets'], 'organizer': at['organizer']}

        # add values from sold_tickets_by_event
        if st_pk in ticket_stats_by_event:
            ticket_stats_by_event[st_pk].update(st_value)
        else:
            ticket_stats_by_event[st_pk] = st_value
        # add values from available_tickets_by_event
        if at_pk in ticket_stats_by_event:
            ticket_stats_by_event[at_pk].update(at_value)
        else:
            ticket_stats_by_event[at_pk] = at_value

    return ticket_stats_by_event
```

Also, you can break this into three loops where in first and second you fetch sold and available tickets for a particular organization. I haven't used one liner functions to make it more readable.